# Jetpack Compose LazyListState Weird Bug

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

Passing a LazyListState as a variable into a Lazy Column is creating a weird bug I had never encountered.

```
val listState = rememberLazyListState()
LaunchedEffect(key1 = state.messages.size) {
    if (state.messages.isNotEmpty() && listState.firstVisibleItemIndex < 5) listState.animateScrollToItem(0)
}
```

Here, the Log Statement (printed out on every recomposition) gives the latest state of the first "msg" after every change that is made to that message.

But when the callback "onReply()" is invoked, the argument "msg" still has the old state.

How on earth could that happen when UI got updated but callback is fired with an old state?

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    reverseLayout = true,
    state = listState
) {
    itemsIndexed(
        items = state.messages,
        key = { _, m -> m.msgId }
    ) { i, msg ->
          if (i == 0) {
              Log.i("ChatScreen", "Message with ID: ${msg.msgId} is ${msg.state.name}")
          }
          MessageItem(
              message = msg,
              onReply = {
                  viewModel.reply(msg)
              }
          )
     }
}
```

When variable listState was removed from LazyColumn or rememberLazyListState() is passed into, the bug goes away.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: how `onReply` is called? if you're using it from `pointerInput`, you may need to wrap it with `rememberUpdatedState`, e.g. check out `Modifier.clickable` source code and how `onClick` is being used

Comment: @PhilDukhov Exactly. I modified the code for pointerInput to update as state mutates and it works. But still, I have no idea, what it has to do with passing lazyListState as a variable into the column.

Answer (score 1):

The following code triggers recomposition each time your `state.messages.size` changes:

```
val listState = rememberLazyListState()
LaunchedEffect(key1 = state.messages.size) {
    if (state.messages.isNotEmpty() && listState.firstVisibleItemIndex < 5) listState.animateScrollToItem(0)
}
```

And because you're calling `onReply` from `pointerInput` directly, `pointerInput` captures the first value of `onReply`.

I guess that when you remove `state`, you also remove the `LaunchedEffect`, so there's no recomposition triggered, and you're not experiencing problems because of `pointerInput`.

So first of all, it's a good practice to wrap callbacks with `rememberUpdatedState` before using them in `pointerInput` - check out how `Modifier.clickable` source code and how `onClick` is being used there.

Second one, try to reduce number of recompositions as much as possible - especially with lazy views.

In this case you actually don't need to restart `LaunchedEffect` each time `state.messages.size` changes. Instead you can use `snapshotFlow` like this:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    snapshotFlow { state.messages.size }
        .collectLatest { messagesSize ->
            if (messagesSize > 0 && listState.firstVisibleItemIndex < 5) {
                listState.animateScrollToItem(0)
            }
        }
}
```

It would work if `state` is of Compose `State` type, otherwise you need to also wrap it with `rememberUpdatedState`, e.g.

```
val updatedState by rememberUpdatedState(state)
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    snapshotFlow { updatedState.messages.size }
        ...
```